# CircleCI never completes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, circleci

I have a Ruby/Rails project I inherited. It's a private github repo, and it's hooked up to CircleCI in the standard way: github won't allow a merge til the required CircleCI tests pass. That's fine, but when I create a pull request, I only get "ci/circleci — Waiting for status to be reported" and that never changes (I waited all weekend). I'm not sure where to look for log files, or what might be going wrong. I'm new to CircleCI. Any help? The last item I see in my circleci dashboard is months ago, so it's almost like it's not seeing the new pull request. But I can see github sending it and getting a 200 reply.

BTW, the `circle.yml` just sets the machine timezone, nothing else, nothing fancy.

Comment: Connect by ssh to circleCI container and try to figure out where it sticks.

Comment: Try clicking the "Unfollow on CircleCI" button it's the Project's settings and then refollow it?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to configure the branch settings:

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows-waiting-status/